# "..." in MongoDB Shell (version 3.2)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

Currently running the following aggregate query in my mongo shell: db.zips.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"state":"$state"},{population:{$sum: "$pop}}}])
and when I press enter, "..." shows up with a blinking cursor. Is it taking a long time to run or expecting me to continue typing?

Thanks!

Comment: It means you have  missing curly brace or square bracket in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a brace too much

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {"state":"$state"},
            {population:{$sum: "$pop} // <- Brace at population too much?
        }
    }
])
```